# Kafka and Topic with Multiple Messages Types (Avro) : Consumer(spring cloud spring fails due to the lack of class on classpath

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

**Topic contains two types of messages: PaymentStarted and PaymentCompleted.
There are 2 separated microservices with consumers. 
So :Microservice_1, has consumer1 which should grab the PaymentStarted type;
Microservice_2, has consumer2 which should grab the PaymentCompleted type.
Additionally Microservice_1 contains only PaymentStarted on its jvm classpath and
Microservice_2 contains only PaymentCompleted on its jvm classpath.**

Each service for handling different types of messages.
I am using spring-cloud-stream, so in my Microservice_1 the Consumer 1 has:

```
@StreamListener(target = PayBindings.EVENTS, condition = "headers['eventType']=='com.company.domain.PaymentStarted'")
    void onPaymentEvents(Message<PaymentStarted> message){
    }
```

analogically Microservice_2 the Consumer 2 has:

```
@StreamListener(target = PayBindings.EVENTS, condition = "headers['eventType']=='com.company.domain.PaymentCompleted'")
    void onPaymentEvents(Message<PaymentCompleted> message){
    }
```

Documentations says(https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.0.M1/spring-cloud-stream.html#_using_streamlistener_annotation) that filtering goes before the serialization.

But in my case before condition filters them out, the default deserialiser(in my case io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer) fails due to lack of PaymentCompleted on the classpath at microservice_1. Analogically with microservice_2 and PaymentStarted.
I don't want to mix the domains and keep PaymentStarted and PaymentCompleted pojos in Microservice_1 and Microservice_2.

I tried to solve that with my custom deserializer and it looks that it is doable with handling exception, but it is really tricky.

I am also confused that the doc I mentioned here above says that the filtering out goes before deserializing.

I appreciate your thoughts/comments.

Answer (score 0):

You should really use a different topic for each type.

However, see [Spring for Apache Kafka's ErrorHandlingDeserializer2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/reference/html/#error-handling-deserializer).

Which will catch the exception and the listener container will route the error directly to the container's error handler.

> I am also confused that the doc I mentioned here above says that the filtering out goes before deserializing.

That does not apply when you are using native deserialization, which is much lower down in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

You should consume all messages and inside the function **onPaymentEvents** filter messages needed be each consumer. I suppose you have a single microservice that producer both type of messages.Also I replace the Avro with JSON.